# How can I overcome an error in xfun when kniting an Rmarkdown?

Tags: html, pdf, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

When I try to knit the default Rmarkdown sample in RStudio i cannot convert it to either PDF or HTML.

This appears:

```
Error in xfun::normalize_path(path, ..., must_work = must_work, resolve_symlink = FALSE) : 
  unused argument (resolve_symlink = FALSE)
Calls: <Anonymous> -> normalize_path
Además: Warning message:
Can't find generic `sew` in package knitr to register S3 method.
i This message is only shown to developers using devtools.
i Do you need to update knitr to the latest version? 
Ejecución interrumpida
```

I already tried to remove xfun and reinstall it but it is not working.

Comment: *"Do you need to update knitr to the latest version?"* <- well, do you? What version are you running?

Comment: Yes, [you do](https://yihui.org/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/) (at least update **knitr** and **xfun**).

Comment: I do have updated both packages and still get the same error. I attach the versions
> packageVersion('knitr')
[1] ‘1.30’
> packageVersion('xfun')
[1] ‘0.30’

Comment: knitr 1.30 was released more than 3 years ago, and xfun 0.30 was 20 months ago, so they are definitely outdated (see https://cran.rstudio.com/package=knitr and https://cran.rstudio.com/package=xfun for latest version numbers). If you have tried to update packages and still don't get latest versions, your R version is probably too old and you should upgrade R first (I have mentioned this in the post linked in my previous comment). It will be clearer if you could provide `sessionInfo()` or `xfun::session_info('rmarkdown')` in your post.

Comment: Once I did session Info as you asked, I acknowledged that RStudio was using an outdated version of R in my computer. I eliminated it so as to only select the updated one and now is working fine. 

Thank you so much, I appreciate it a lot.
Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the **xfun** package, or just update all packages:

```r
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

(Posting an answer here so that we could mark posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77483367/559676) as duplicates.)