# R markdown error when knitting any Rmd file

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

i'm not able to knit a file rmarkdown, i receive the same error when I knit  Rmarkdown file (i.e. the example generated by RStudio). Please, let me know if you need further descriptions to help me.

I get the following message:

```
Error in xfun::normalize_path(path, ..., must_work = must_work, resolve_symlink = FALSE) : 
  argument inutilisé (resolve_symlink = FALSE)
Calls: <Anonymous> -> normalize_path
Exécution arrêtée
```

i tried to remove the package "xfun" from the packages section. And reinstall

Comment: You need to update or reinstall the **xfun** package, which you seem to have done but not successfully. I don't know why. Please at least provide `xfun::session_info('rmarkdown')` in your post.

Comment: thank you for your help , i tried to remove xfun and reinstall it again so it works now and i can knit my doc .

Comment: for the result of  : xfun::session_info('rmarkdown') I have this : Package version: base64enc_0.1.3 bslib_0.3.1     digest_0.6.29   evaluate_0.23   fastmap_1.1.0   fs_1.5.2        glue_1.6.2     
  graphics_4.0.5  grDevices_4.0.5 highr_0.10      htmltools_0.5.2 jquerylib_0.1.4 jsonlite_1.8.0  knitr_1.38     
  magrittr_2.0.3  methods_4.0.5   R6_2.5.1        rappdirs_0.3.3  rlang_1.0.2     rmarkdown_2.13  sass_0.4.1     
  stats_4.0.5     stringi_1.7.6   stringr_1.4.0   tinytex_0.49    tools_4.0.5     utils_4.0.5     xfun_0.30      
  yaml_2.3.5     
Pandoc version: 2.19.2

Comment: Good to know it works now! This post is actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77483367/559676.